# Populating elements data from the DB?

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a number of elements on a web page, that are scattered, meaning that they cannot be placed in a grid. The content has a title, some other data like Feedback, Recommendation, Notes, Customers, Suppliers, Competitors, etc etc that are placed in a certain format on the webpage. The values for these fields will be populated from the Database. I'm not sure which control would be most suitable for this requirement? Right now I'm using **div** tags to place the elements in the required format. But I'm guessing it's not going to be very easy/clean to populate data in a **div** tag. I wanted to know if it will be better to use a  or an  control or anything else. Please advise.

Comment: you can can use inline binding ,

[Inline binding][1]

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744947/inline-data-binding-asp-net-tags-not-executing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be best that it will be a `div` with style of `position:absolute`.
No need for any ASP.NET special server control.

Comment: but then how do i populate data in this <div> from the database?

Comment: On the server-side. Say for example give each div a unique id and runat="server" and access it accordingly.